# Given a number of variables to test for definedness, how to (easily) find out the one which was left undefined?

Tags: perl

Today I saw this piece of code:

```
if (    not defined($reply_address) 
     or not defined($from_name) 
     or not defined($subject) 
     or not defined($date) )
{ 
  die "couldn’t glean the required information!"; 
}
```

(Jeffrey Friedl, "Mastering Regular Expressions", p. 59, 3rd ed.)

and I thought "How can I know which variable misfired?"

Of course, if there are only 4 variables to test, as in the example above, one could come up with:

```
if ( not defined $reply_address ) 
{ 
  die "\$reply_address is not defined" 
}
elsif ( not defined $from_name )
{
  die "\$from_name is not defined"
}
elsif ...
```

But what if there are 14 variables? Or 40...?
One still needs to go through all of them, manually testing each and every one?

Isn't there a shorter, more "magical" way of telling which variable was left undefined?

Comment: I don't have a magic enough answer, but `die '$reply_address is not defined' unless defined $reply_address;` would be a cleaner example of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with [symbolic references](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/prog/ch08_04.htm), though using them is generally not a great idea, and it can only be done with package variables, not lexically scoped variables (and lexically scoped variables are preferred to package variables -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019829/45978) for a brief comparison of the two).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.014;

our($foo1) = 1;
our($bar1) = undef;
our($baz1) = 3;

foreach my $name (qw(foo1 bar1 baz1)) {
    {
        no strict 'refs';
        my($value) = $$name;
        warn "$name: is not defined" unless defined $value;
        say "$name: <$value>";
    }
}
```

Using `warn` instead of `die` for illustrative purposes.

```
</tmp> $ ./test.pl
foo1: <1>
bar1: is not defined at ./test.pl line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 17.
bar1: <>
baz1: <3>
```

You can also just loop through all of the variables using common code to check them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.014;

my($foo2) = 1;
my($bar2) = undef;
my($baz2) = 3;

foreach my $vardef (["foo2", $foo2], ["bar2", $bar2], ["baz2", $baz2]) {
    my($name) = $vardef->[0];
    my($value)  = $vardef->[1];

    warn "$name: is not defined" unless defined $value;
    say "$name: <$value>";
}
```

which gives similar output:

```
foo2: <1>
bar2: is not defined at ./test.pl line 29.
Use of uninitialized value $value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 30.
bar2: <>
baz2: <3>
```

Finally, if you can manage to get the variables into a hash, you can loop through the keys of the hash and test them that way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.014;

my($vars) = {
    foo3 => 1,
    bar3 => undef,
    baz3 => 3,
};

foreach my $name (sort keys %$vars) {
    my($value)  = $vars->{$name};

    warn "$name: is not defined" unless defined $value;
    say "$name: <$value>";
}
```

I threw the `sort` in there because I like deterministic behavior...

```
bar3: is not defined at ./test.pl line 42.
Use of uninitialized value $value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 43.
bar3: <>
baz3: <3>
foo3: <1>
```

If the test really was as simple as `die if ! defined` then I would probably just list them out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.014;

my($foo4) = 1;
my($bar4) = undef;
my($baz4) = 3;

die qq([ERROR] \$foo4 not defined\n) unless defined $foo4;
die qq([ERROR] \$bar4 not defined\n) unless defined $bar4;
die qq([ERROR] \$baz4 not defined\n) unless defined $baz4;
```

which just gives us:

```
[ERROR] $bar4 not defined
```

The last approach is just very straightforward and unambiguous. If the test is not as dead simple as this, then I'd go with the second approach. If you're worried about a list of 40 (or even 14) checks of this nature, then I'd look at the design.

See also this [PadWalker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5200789/45978) code example for a very complicated version of the first option, but allowing lexically scoped variables.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a table to simplify a little bit:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $reply_address = "xyz";
my $from_name;
my $subject = "test";
my $date;

my @checks = (
    [\$reply_address, '$reply_adress'],
    [\$from_name, '$from_name'],
    [\$subject, '$subject'],
    [\$date, '$date'],
);

for my $check (@checks) {
    if (not defined ${$check->[0]}) {
        die $check->[1] . " is not defined";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be done with a string-eval:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($reply_address, $from_name, $subject, $date) = ('', '', undef, '');

for my $var (qw(reply_address from_name subject date)) {
    my $defined;
    eval "\$defined = defined \$$var";
    die "eval failed: $@" if $@;
    die "\$$var is not defined" unless $defined;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, this is a very bad idea. You could literally do the exact same idea with a hash and skip the `eval`. Few good ideas involve `eval`. This should not have 2 upvotes.

Comment: It would help me if you could explain why this idea is "very bad". Not in general, but in this concrete usage.

Comment: Because using `eval` on strings allows users to execute arbitrary code on your system. While your specific case might *seem* safe enough, you never know what security holes other users will introduce when they use your code. And as security holes go, this is a big one. And also because this is exactly how hashes work, you take a string which you use as a key to get a value. E.g. `die "$var is not defined" unless defined $data{$var}`.

Comment: Here's are two excellent write-ups on the (mis-)use of string eval: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/perl/IDS35-PL.+Do+not+invoke+the+eval+form+with+a+string+argument and https://perlmaven.com/string-eval